# Authentication.Login: AuthenticationService is set to null

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am having a nervous-breakdown over the following:

I want to automatically login a recently created user that has been added to the database.
User data is reflected in the database (SQL Server 2008) after being created.

The login code is below:

---

```
            DatingSite.Views.Signup signupPage = e.Content as DatingSite.Views.Signup;

            signupPage.SignupComplete += (se, ev) =>
            {
                WebContext.Current.Authentication.Login(new LoginParameters(ev.NewUser.email_address, ev.NewUser.password),
                    (LoginCompleteCallback) =>
                    {
                        GetUserInformation();
                    }, null);
            };
```

---

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
public class AuthenticationService : AuthenticationBase<User>
{
}

public class User : UserBase
{
    // Profile properties that should be exposed as the user object
    // User information
    public string CurrentTheme { get; set; }
}
```

---

When attempting to execute this login instruction I receive an error that is at the bottom of this message.

---

I inserted the following into my web config file:

---

authentication mode="Forms"

---

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService.<>c_*DisplayClass1`1.<WrapCompleteAction>b__0(T ao)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.ApplicationServices.LoginOperation.InvokeCompleteAction()
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.OperationBase.Complete(Object result)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationOperation.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationOperation.<>c__DisplayClass1.<HandleAsyncCompleted>b__0(Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationOperation.RunInSynchronizationContext(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationOperation.HandleAsyncCompleted(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.AsyncResultBase.Complete()
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.ApplicationServices.WebAuthenticationService.HandleOperationComplete(OperationBase operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.LoadOperation.<>c__DisplayClass4`1.b*_0(LoadOperation`1 arg)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.LoadOperation`1.InvokeCompleteAction()
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.OperationBase.Complete(Object result)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.LoadOperation.Complete(DomainClientResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteLoad(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.<>c_*DisplayClass1b.b*_17(Object )}

---

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have instantiated a WebContext object with a FormsAuthentication authentication property. If you hadn't then the expected error would be something like a NotSupportedException. But just in case, add the following lines to your App.xaml.cs.

```
        var webContext = new WebContext();
        webContext.Authentication = new FormsAuthentication();
        ApplicationLifetimeObjects.Add(webContext);
```